# What does [[ $something = {{* ]] do in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting

Found this expression in some shell scripts. What does the double-curly brace star "{{*" mean?

```
if [[ "$_DIR" = {{* ]]
```

I've looked through http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html and tried searching for it, but can't find an explanation.

Comment: It's a pattern match.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are bad form. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html for conventions on environment variable names -- keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means: "if $_DIR" expands to a string starting with "{{"...

Thus, `{{*` doesn't actually mean anything to bash at all, more than if you wrote

```
for file in {{*; do printf '%s\n' "$file"; done
```

...would mean that `{{*` had any more meaning to bash than "all files whose names start with two curly braces".

---

Search for "pattern matching" in [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more on `[[` and how it's extended to offer functionality not present in `test`, including both glob-style pattern matching and native regular expression support.

Alternately, look for `[[…]]` in [the Conditional Constructs section of the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

---

Incidentally, the POSIX sh equivalent to this would be:

```
case $_DIR in
  {{*) echo "put the true branch here" ;;
  *)   echo "put the false branch here" ;;
esac
```